# UWP .appinstaller - "Error in parsing the app package."

Tags: c#, xamarin, uwp

I have create a .appinstaller XML file with details of my UWP Package and linked it to a Web page where Users can install from. For some reason this gives me an error of "Error in parsing the app package." when trying to install the App. I have followed the steps as mention on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/install-related-set

Below is the xml used to create the .appinstaller. Any Idea what I could be missing?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AppInstaller
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/appinstaller/2017"
    Version="1.0.0.0" 
    Uri="http://mywebservice.azurewebsites.net/APP_UWP.appinstaller" > 

    <MainBundle 
        Name="MainApp"
        Publisher="CN=EGSolutions"
        Version="1.0.0.0"
        Uri="http://mywebservice.azurewebsites.net/EGClockingXamarin.UWP_1.0.8.0_x86_x64_arm_Debug.appxbundle" />

    <Dependencies>
        <Package Name="Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.2.1" Publisher="CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US" Version="14.0.24605.0" ProcessorArchitecture="x86" Uri="http://foobarbaz.com/Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.2.1.appx" />
        <Package Name="Microsoft.VCLibs.ARM.Debug.14.00" Publisher="CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US" Version="14.0.24605.0" ProcessorArchitecture="x64" Uri="http://foobarbaz.com/Microsoft.VCLibs.ARM.Debug.14.00.appx" />
    </Dependencies>

</AppInstaller>
```

Comment: Please make sure you have installed the signing certificate to the Trusted People or Trusted Publishers Certification Authorities store on the device. Besides, If you don't use the appinstaller xml file but just  [Sideload your app package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/packaging-uwp-apps#sideload-your-app-package), can your app be installed?

Comment: Yes Im able to install the APP when not using appinstaller.

Comment: It is likely that App Installer is not able to access the app package from the web server. Can you confirm that you are able to access the webserver otherwise. One simple test you can perform is – Just remove the custom scheme in front of the URI and enter that in your browser address bar. If you have access to the web server, the browser should prompt you to download the app package.

Comment: @BreezeLiu-MSFT True when trying to reach the url via browser i get the "404 - File or directory not found" Server Error. Any idea of properties that the files should be?

Comment: It should be your web server issue, you should replace the **uri** an available website where you can put your app package on and the user can download the package files.